# Словосочетание "прохождение обучения"?

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли разница: "Прохождение обучения по применению..." или "Обучение по применению..."?

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть контекст.

Comment: Действительно, без контекста сложно подсказать.

Answer (score 1):

Это разные выражения, например, можно сравнить:

**Обучение по применению** оружия проводится в учебных центрах, там же вы получите сертификат **о прохождении обучения по применению** оружия.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что есть. Сравните. (А) 1. Он работал со студентами: проводил обучение по применению... . 2.  Он работал со студентами: проводил прохождение обучения по применению... . Или еще. (Б) 1. Обучение по применению... я прошел вполне успешно. 2.Прохождение обучения по применению... я прошел вполне успешно. 
На мой взгляд, в первом варианте речь идет о каком-то конкретном курсе обучения. Второй - больше подходит для описания процесса обучения вообще. 1. Прохождение обучения по применению... в нашей школе стоит 5000 рублей. 2. Обучение по применению... обычно стоит от 4 до 6 тысяч рублей. Если кто-то проводит это обучение, то речи о "прохождении" быть не может (пример А1).